# Wrong currency info being returned when calling spot price endpoint using Python

Tags: coinbase-api

I have noticed that the data endpoint for getting the spot price is returning the wrong currency information when using Python. I am using a **currency_pair** of *BTC-USD* but getting results for *GBP*.

Example:

```
price = client.get_spot_price(currency_pair = 'BTC-USD')
```

Response:

```
{
  "amount": "5578.85", 
  "base": "BTC", 
  "currency": "GBP"
}
```

Any ideas on whats causing this problem?

Comment: same issue here, though mine defaults to `EUR` (I'm in the US). There'd certainly be an ass-backwards way of getting the price by first calling the `.get_exchange_rates()` method, but I feel like that's unnecessary—and that there's something fundamental I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround, though not using the official Coinbase client, would be as follows:

```
import requests
import json

# Do This to Avoid Warning
headers = {
    'CB-VERSION': '2017-12-08'
}

# Make Request
data = requests.get('https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/sell/', headers=headers).text

# Parse Response, Get Amount
price = json.loads(data)['data']['amount]
```

Obviously not very robust in terms of handling errors, exceptions, or any other types of assertions one would need (that the official client should have) that would be needed to provide the confidence needed for actual buys/sells/transfers.

EDIT: UPDATE

Apparently this is a known issue:

Read here:

https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-python/issues/32

Supposedly already fixed in the github `master`, though obviously not reflected in the `pip` version yet.

Quoting user [kflecki](https://github.com/klefki):

*I fixed this by going into the client.py file and modifying the code to look like this. Works just fine now, however would be nice for the files to come like this. But it's a simple fix that you can do on your own.*

```
def get_spot_price(self, **params):
"""https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#get-spot-price"""
if 'currency_pair' in params:
currency_pair = params['currency_pair']
else:
currency_pair = 'BTC-USD'
response = self._get('v2', 'prices', currency_pair, 'spot', data=params)
return self._make_api_object(response, APIObject)
```

*And now the command works like so:*

```
eth_price = client.get_spot_price(currency_pair = 'ETH-USD')
```